# how to show different number of records until a submit button is pressed in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just want that if a user enters the name of item in text box then particular details from database should be displayed on the same page in a table below. Right now its working for one item. Now if a user wants to select multiple items and want to show record of each selected item on the page until a submit button is not pressed. Here is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sales</title>
<script>
function search(string){
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "sales_search.php?s="+string, true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
```

I have not included the CSS code to shorten it.

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

function sales_result()
{
$submit = $_GET['finish'];
if(isset($_GET['mname']) && $_GET['mname'] != '')
{
$name = $_GET['mname'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `medicine_item_record` WHERE `medicine_item_name` LIKE '%$name%'";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    while($check =='submit')
    {
    echo strtoupper($row['company_name']);

    }
}
}
?>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
<h1>Sales</h1><span style="font-family: tahoma, sans-serif, arial; margin-left: 150px; font-size: 13px;"></span><br/><br/>
<table border=1>
<tr><td><input type="text" placeholder="Type to search.." onkeyup="search(this.value)" id="text" ></td>
<td><input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Quantity" name="quantity"      id="text"></td>
<td><input type ="submit" name="finish" value="finish"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="search">


</div>
</div>
<table border=1 width='100%' align= 'center'>
<tr><?php sales_result() ?> </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

code for sales_search.php is as follows:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != '')
{
$s = $_GET['s'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `medicine_item_record` WHERE `medicine_item_name` LIKE '%$s%'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $name = $row['medicine_item_name'];
    echo "<div style='' id='searchtitle'>"."<a style='font-family: verdana; text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='sales.php?mname=$name'>" . $name . "</div>";

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by Multiple Items. Taking a stab that you mean if the user enters different search terms? For example: "depressor, swab". You would need to parse this in some way before building your Query. If your separator (my example it's the comma) is in the string, explode it and then make your query using a loop:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ''){
  $search_str = trim($_GET['s']);
  if(strpos($search_str, ",")){
    // Multiple Search Terms found
    $s = explode($search_str, ",");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `medicine_item_record` WHERE `medicine_item_name` LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($s[0]), $con) . "%'";
    for($i=1;$i<count($s);$i++){
       $sql .= " OR `medicine_item_name` LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($s[$i]), $con) . "%'";
    }
    $sql .= ";";
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `medicine_item_record` WHERE `medicine_item_name` LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($search_str, $con) . "%';";
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row['medicine_item_name'];
    echo "<div style='' id='searchtitle'>"."<a style='font-family: verdana; text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='sales.php?mname=$name'>" . $name . "</div>";
  }
}
?>
```

**Edit after your comment:**

That is happening in the response of your AJAX call:

`document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

This line of code replaces the content in that element. You will want to append the response:

```
var current = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = current + xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want that if I select any medicine from the search box then its details should be printed in the table below. Now when I search for another medicine it is printing that medicine details and not showing the previous details. Each time it is printing the details for the current item not holding the previous details.

Comment: Its not working the way I want, it's just duplicating the possibilities/matches of search word in the drop down list and nothing else.